# display sum per user elegantly in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

trying to display the final mark per student. But instead of just showing the result of sum , it displays a chunk of query set: for example:

```
Annie <QuerySet [{'studName': None, 'attendance__sum': 3}, {'studName': 1, 'attendance__sum': 2}, {'studName': 2, 'attendance__sum': 1}]>
```

and same goes to the rest of the students.

I would like to display it like :

Annie 2

Benny 3

Charlie 4

My view:

```
def attStudName(request):
    studentName = MarkAtt.objects.all()
    mark = MarkAtt.objects.values('studName').annotate(Sum('attendance'))
    context = {
        'studentName' : studentName,
        'mark' : mark

    }
    return render(request,'show-name.html',context)
```

My template:

```
{% for y in mark %}

{% for x in studentName %}  

 <p>{{x.studName}}</p> <p> {{mark}}</p>

 {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

How do i display each student name with their own mark accordingly? And how do i display the mark without the

Edited:

Model.py:

```
class Namelist(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    program = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    year = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    studType = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    courseType = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    nationality = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    VMSAcc = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    classGrp = models.ForeignKey('GroupInfo', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)


class MarkAtt(models.Model):
    studName = models.ForeignKey(Namelist,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    classGrp = models.ForeignKey(GroupInfo, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    currentDate = models.DateField(default=now())
    week = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    attendance = models.IntegerField(default=100) #1 is present
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add model code

Comment: Did you set a `ForeignKey` to a "student" model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below should return a queryset with student names and marks. Two separate queries should not be needed.

```
students = MarkAtt.objects.values('studName').annotate(mark=Sum('attendance'))
```

If `studName` is a foreign key, do this `.values('studName__name')`

Then in your context you can just add:

```
context = {
    students = students
}
```

You can then loop through `students` in you template and display data as:

```
<p>{{x.studName}}</p> <p> {{x.mark}}</p>
```

Comment: Hi there. Yes, my studName is a ForeignKey to Namelist. I tried to put 'studName_name' but it shows me an error : "Cannot resolve keyword 'studName_name' into field. Choices are: attendance, classGrp, classGrp_id, currentDate, id, studName, studName_id, week" i have added my models above

Comment: Use double underscore and also point to the field that contains the student name

Comment: Get it, I need to put {{x.studName__name}} as well. Do u know how can i export this information to excel?

Comment: This is a completely different question, and not at all part of the original. I would recommend logging a new question for that.  Yes, that would be how you reference the field in the template.

Comment: I have logged a new question. Mayb you could take a look at that question? My export is not working currently. Heres the link :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58010268/how-to-export-information-display-in-table-to-excel-django

Comment: I have added an answer to the new question

Answer (score 1):

You are overcomplicating things. Given the following simple context:

```
students = MarkAtt.objects.values('studName').annotate(mark=Sum('attendance'))
context = {
    'students' : students,
}
```

you can do in the template:

```
{% for student in students %}  
    <p>{{student.studName}}</p> <p> {{ student.mark}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```