# How to export information display in table to excel django

Tags: python, django

I want to export the information display in the template under table tag to excel. I already tried to implement code but it is now exporting the information.

This is my template:

```
<div id="info" style="padding-left: 130px">
 <table class="table table-hover" style="width: 1200px;">
<thead>
     <tr><th> Student Name</th>
     <th> Attendance Mark </th>
     </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    {% for student in students %}
    <tr><td>{{student.studName__VMSAcc}}</td>
        <td>{{student.mark}}</td>
        </tr>   
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
  </table>
  <a href="{% url 'exportdata' %}">export data</a>
  </div>
```

My `View.py`

```
 #to display the attended students in the table form
 def attStudName(request):

students = MarkAtt.objects.values('studName__VMSAcc').annotate(mark=Sum('attendance'))
if (mark): 
    ttlmark = (mark/200) *100
    context = {
    'students' : students,
    'ttlmark': ttlmark
    }
return render(request,'show-name.html',context)


#to extract the infomation displayed in the table.
def file_load_view(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="report.csv"'
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['Student Name', 'Attendance'])

    students = MarkAtt.objects.values('studName__VMSAcc').annotate(mark=Sum('attendance'))

    #convert the students query set to a values list as the writerow expects a list/tuple
    students = students.values_list('studName__VMSAcc', 'attendance')

    for student in students:
        writer.writerow(student)
    return response
```

My `URLS.py`

```
 url(r'^export/csv/$', views.file_load_view, name="export_data")
```

Above is my updated assisted by Marcell. Ive managed to export the required data. My question is: am I allowed to use if-else statement in my views.py? What i am trying to do is, to convert the mark to percentage. If students have 200 marks, then it will display 100%, if 100 marks then 90% or so.

Comment: You can consider using CSV module https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html that can create a valid CSV file for you

Comment: Please only use the relevant tags (fixed).

Comment: It looks like you already have some code doing the right thing (well, possibly not in the most straightforward way but), so what's your question actually ? NB : please do not answer "it doesn't work" - if it "doesn't work" then you have to explain _exactly_ HOW it doesn't work (and if you have an exception, post the exact exception message AND the full traceback).

Comment: You can use [django-tables2](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to easily export data in a couple of formats, apart from other userful features. I can write you a snippet if you're interested in this package.

Comment: Currently, when i cleck the link: export-data, it just refreshed the page and no excel file is downloaded. So i m not sure what is the problem with it as it doesnt prompt any error. Just not downloading the content of the table into excel sheet @brunodesthuilliers

Comment: I dont mind trying out any method that would help me to achieve my desired actions. Would appreciate if you share it with me. @JordanM. thank you

Comment: @Puteri please _edit your question_ with those details.

Comment: And while you're at it please fix your view code indentation - in Python, indentation is a crucial part of the syntax.

Comment: "when i cleck the link: export-data, it just refreshed the page " => first check the rendered html in your browser's dev panel to find out if you have the correct url.  Also, check what happens in your dev server's outputs (in the terminal from which you run ./manage.py runserver). Eventually add a couple `print("here")` cals in you view to find out if your view is actually executed. And edit your question to add what you find out. Basic debugging techniques, really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all the `report_line` dictionary is referencing a `student` variable that does not exists in the scope of the method. Based on your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58008040/display-sum-per-user-elegantly-in-django/58008183?noredirect=1#comment102428919_58008183) I presume you want to export the data displayed in your template.

Also I would recommend updating current question with the complete code set.

In order to achieve that you can do something like this:

```
import csv

from django.http import HttpResponse

def file_load_view(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachement; filename="report.csv"'

    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['Student Name', 'Attendance'])

    students = MarkAtt.objects.values('studName__VMSAcc').annotate(mark=Sum('attendance'))

    # Note: we convert the students query set to a values_list as the writerow expects a list/tuple       
    students = students.values_list('studName__VMSAcc', 'mark')

    for student in students:
        writer.writerow(student)

    return response
```

Your url will look something like this:

```
 url(r'^export/csv/$', views.file_load_view, name='export_data')
```

In your template:

```
<a href="{% url 'export_data' %}">Export Data</a>
```

This is for exporting data to `csv` file. Looking at your file name extension it seems this is the behaviour you are looking for. If you want to export to `excel` file I would recommend looking at a third party library like `xlwt`

Comment: Hi Marcell, tried to change my code to yours. Managed to export the file accordingly. However, the data being exported is not correct. like in the website: the student, Annie has 200 marks but when exported the value is 100 mark only. I guess the sum does not work correctly? Hw do i resolve this?

Comment: okay fixed it. Instead of " students = students.values_list('studName__VMSAcc', 'attendance')" i shld change the attendance to mark. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ahh yes, I will update the answer. Please accept if this is the correct answer.

Comment: Sure done! :) Anyway, is it possible to do if-else statement stated about under my Views.py. What i am trying to do is, to convert the mark to percentage. If students have 200 marks, then it will display 100%, if 100 marks then 90% or so.

Comment: Have I look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19286834/django-calculate-percentage-based-on-object-count I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: im not able to follow because of the different situation

Comment: hi marcell, would u mind to help me take a look at this problem of mine again? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58039235/convert-sum-value-to-percentage-by-userid-django appreciate much

Answer (score 4):

You can use [django-tables2](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Install it and add it to `INSTALLED_APPS`. You'll also need to install `tablib` for the export feature. Create a `tables.py` file under your app folder:

```py
import django_tables2 as tables
from .models import Student

class StudentTable(tables.Table):
    export_formats = ['xls', 'xlsx', 'csv']  # a list of formats you'll like to export to
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('name', 'mark')
        # There are more Meta attributes you can use, just look for them in the docs.
```

Then use the `SingleTableView` class with `ExportMixin` in your `views.py`:

```py
from django_tables2.views import SingleTableView
from django_tables2.export.views import ExportMixin
from .models import Student
from .tables import StudentTable

class StudentList(ExportMixin, SingleTableView):
    model = Student
    table_class = StudentTable
    export_name = 'students_assistance'
    template_name = 'students/student_list.html'
```

Finally your `student_list.html` template should look like this:

```html
{% load django_tables2 %}
<div>
  {% for format in table.export_formats %}
    <a href="{% export_url format %}">.{{ format }}</a>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
{% render_table table %}
```

There's a lot more you can do with `django-tables2`, this is just a basic implementation. You can also combine it with [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/).

Answer (score 1):

See the below example to export the data in csv format:

```
import csv
from django.http import HttpResponse

def some_view(request):
    # Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate CSV header.
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.csv"'

    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['First row', 'Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'])
    writer.writerow(['Second row', 'A', 'B', 'C', '"Testing"', "Here's a quote"])

    return response
```

You can modifiy your code similar to above example. There are more example in offical django document see this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/outputting-csv/).

Comment: may i know what is foo, bar, baz represents? I need to import the data dynamically based on what is display in the template.

Comment: @Puteri https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable  - this is __example__ code so you get the principle.