# convert sum value to percentage by userid django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to convert the total sum to a percentage by **userid** but an error pops up when I try to run the following program.

The error is:

> name 'mark' is not defined

Below is my code for **views.py**

```
def attStudName(request):
students = MarkAtt.objects.values('studName__VMSAcc').annotate(mark=Sum('attendance'), percentage=(F('mark')/1100) *100)
    context = {
    'students' : students,

        }
    context = {
    'students' : students,
    'ttl' : ttl
        }
    return render(request,'show-name.html',context)
```

Managed to get the value out but it returned all zero. Here is my data:

Student Name| Attendance Mark | Percentage

anni    |           800    |            0

benny | 800 |   0

Comment: But... 'mark' *isn't* defined.

Comment: The mark is defined in the annotate(). Hm

Comment: I can't understand how you can think that. That seems a fairly basic misunderstanding of how variable definitions work.

Comment: what is the best way to achieve that

Comment: Sorry, you really can't just replace a question with another one, especially not one someone already put in the effort to answer.

Answer (score 0):

There was some '' missing in my answer. Try this:

```
from django.db.models import F
students = MarkAtt.objects.values('studName__VMSAcc').annotate(mark=Sum('attendance'), percentage=(F('mark') / 1100) * 100)
```

Then in the template:

```
{% for student in students %}
    {{ student.studName__VMSAcc }}
    {{ student.mark }}
    {{ student.percentage }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: the error says "'dict' object has no attribute 'mark'". the mark is an attribute that i declare in annotate()... how do i resolve this

Comment: mark and percentage are not attribute fields in my model. it is just variable that ive declared in the view. mark is assigned to the total mark of each student. But i would need to display in percentage..

Comment: how do i display it on the template?

Comment: is there any better way that i can compute the percentage? is there a way i declare one db attribute that save the total mark of the student?

Comment: it returned zero.

Comment: Can´t predict the result without your data, but if you get a result, it´s working.

Comment: updated my question with data. So if the mark is 800, (800/1100) * 100 shld return me 72% and not 0. i think the 'mark' did not pass in the value to the percentage function?